# Making bibliography single spaced without setspace package

Tags: bibliographies, line-spacing

I am writing my thesis and I would like the Bibliography to be single spaced.

I've read about using the `\singlespace` command, but I think this requires using the `setspace` package which I don't want to do, because this makes all my figure captions single spaced (which I don't want).

I am using `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.1}` in my preamble to set the spacing for the document.

I am just using the default bibliography settings. So I'm just using:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{refs}
```

to make my bibliography. Is there a command I can put here to make it single spaced?

Alternatively, if anyone can tell me how to retain double spaced figure captions with `setspace` that would also work!

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, you could change `\baselinestretch` back to the default (1.2?). Have you tried that?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}` before the bibliography, but really you have `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.1}`  ???? double spacing is a typographic disaster at the best of times but this is  way more than that, "double" spacing is usually set with less than 2, eg the setspace package uses 1.667

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but it is a thesis, so it almost certainly has to be a typographical disaster as a condition of graduation :(.

Answer (score 8):

As a side note, I would use

```
\linespread{2.1}\selectfont
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.1}
```

in the preamble.

To answer your question, load the package `etoolbox` and insert the following line in your preamble

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}
```

This will change the line spread to 1 as soon as the bibliography starts.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{someguykey2010,
author="SomeGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2010,
journal="A Journal",
}
@article{someotherguykey2013,
author="SomeOtherGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2013,
journal="A Journal",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}

\usepackage{lipsum} %just for dummy text


\begin{document}

\linespread{2.1}\selectfont

\lipsum[1]

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you don't want to load `etoolbox`, simply issue

```
\linespread{1}\selectfont
```

before your bibliography.

Comment: What change I need in `\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}` to use for biblatex+\printbibliography

Comment: @Mr.EU For `biblatex` you have to use `\AtBeginBibliography{\linespread{1}\selectfont}`.

Answer (score 1):

At some point I wrote or found (?) the following to make my bibliography more compact as I didn't like the standard spacing:

```
% stop the bibliography from being too spaced out
\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \section*{References\@mkboth{References}{References}}\list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
  \itemsep\z@\parsep\z@\topsep\z@\parskip\z@
  \usecounter{enumi}}
  \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
```

As others have said you probably also want to add something like `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}` to this in order to make the line spacing reasonable. (I agree with David's comment that double spacing is a "typographic disaster".)