# Adjusting the space in the references

Tags: biblatex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=true,
        style=ieee,
        citestyle=numeric-comp,
        sorting=none,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        url=true,
        mincitenames=2,
        maxcitenames=2,
        ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}

\linespread{1.5}
\selectfont 

\chapter{One}
\begin{refsection}
Cite this  \cite{this} and that \cite{that}


\printbibliography
\end{refsection}


\chapter{Two}
\begin{refsection}  
Cite this  \cite{this} and that \cite{that2}


\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

.bib:

```
@Article{this,
  author       = {jay A},
  title        = {ABC},
  year         = {2008},
  volume       = {16},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {841--859},
  journaltitle = {Unknown},
  publisher    = {Unknown},
}

@Article{that,
  author       = {jay B},
  title        = {gjh},
  year         = {2008},
  volume       = {16},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {841--859},
  journaltitle = {Unknown},
  publisher    = {Unknown},
}

@Article{that2,
  author       = {jay C},
  title        = {aersf},
  year         = {2008},
  volume       = {16},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {841--859},
 journaltitle = {Unknown},
 publisher    = {Unknown},
 }
```

What I need:

1. no linegap for reference section. Unable to get proper result using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223014/making-bibliography-single-spaced-without-setspace-package).
2. increase space between two bib items.

It is preferable if don't need to change linespread every time. From [here](https://wiki.math.cmu.edu/iki/wiki/tips/20140712-bibtex-spacing.html) Miktex doesn't have bibspacing package. and alternative approach says "Command \bibitemsep already defined. \newlength{\bibitemsep}"

Example: [image]

Comment: Maybe you should prefer `setspace` to do the spacing for you: [Double line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/35864), but maybe you shouldn't. (http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-linespace.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize\linespread{1}\selectfont}
```

to get a single-spaces bibliography.

You can control the space between items with `\bibitemsep`

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
```

Seems sensible here.

Comment: unfortunately, no change is happening. I added these commands before `\addbibresource`.

Comment: @Mr.EU In your MWE there is indeed little change. if you look at entries that span over multiple lines though, you will find that the entries themselves are single-spaced, yet the space between the entries is about as large as on the screenshot. If that is not what you wanted, please explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: example is bad :(